# ¿Como se usa la relación de objetos en java?

Tags: java

Como se representaria en codigo, por ejemplo, "la clase persona tiene un vehiuclo, pero esta puede o no tener otro vehiculo".

este es el codigo que tengo

```
public class Personanatural{

//ATRIBUTOS

String nombre;
String cedula;
private Vehiculo vehiculo;
private Licencia licencia; 
private Tecnomecanica tecnomecanica;

//Constructor

public Personanatural(String nombre, String cedula, Vehiculo vehiculo, Licencia licencia, Tecnomecanica tecnomecanica){
    this.nombre = nombre;
    this.cedula = cedula;
    this.vehiculo = vehiculo;
    this.licencia = licencia;
    this.tecnomecanica = tecnomecanica;
}

public void modificarNombre(String nombre){
    this.nombre = nombre;
}

public String darNombre(){
    return nombre;
}

public void modificarCedula(String cedula){
    this.cedula = cedula;
}

public String darCedula(){
    return cedula;
}

public void modificarVehiculo(Vehiculo vehiculo){
    this.vehiculo = vehiculo;
}

public Vehiculo darVehiculo(){
    return vehiculo;
}

public void modificarLicencia(Licencia licencia){
    this.licencia = licencia;
}

public Licencia darLicencia(){
    return licencia;
}

public void modificarTecnomecanica(Tecnomecanica tecnomecanica){
    this.tecnomecanica = tecnomecanica;
}

public Tecnomecanica darTecnomecanica(){
    return tecnomecanica;
}


}
```

Comment: Deberías poner lo que tengas de código para que podamos ayudarte. Saludos :)

Answer (score 0):

Más que `se representa` prefiero decir `se puede implementar así`; puede haber otras variaciones pero la que muestras es la más normal.

Para el *tiene un* basta con el código que muestras, la diferencia entre forzar a que sea uno o que pueda ser cero o uno se implementaría permitiendo o no valores `null` en el atributo, y programar de forma adecuada:

- Si no se permite `null`, deberías asegurarte de que se pasa el atributo en el constructor y verificar que no es `null`.
- Si se permite, asegurarte de que antes de usarlo el código de la clase compruebe si es `null` para evitar un `NullPointerException`.

Answer (score 0):

Para poder agregarle al objeto persona de 0 a muchos vehiculos el atributo vehiculo debes ponerlo como un arreglo, asi pueden ser ninguno, uno o varios

ejemplo

```
//ATRIBUTOS
private String nombre;
private String cedula;
private ArrayList<Vehiculo> vehiculo;
private Licencia licencia;
private Tecnomecanica tecnomecanica;
```

y los métodos de obtener y establecer serian así

```
public ArrayList<Vehiculo> darVehiculo() { return this.vehiculo; }

public void modificarVehiculo(ArrayList<Vehiculo> vehiculo) { this.vehiculo = vehiculo; }
```